# Range between datetime error

Tags: python, pandas

I want to ask, how to make range in datetime. I already try to make range, but i did not work. My code is following below:

```
import pandas
import os
import datetime
import numpy as np
import glob

def convert_stamp_to_date(stamp):
    try:
        d = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(stamp)
    except:
        d = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
    d = datetime.datetime(d.year, d.month, d.day, d.hour, d.minute, d.second)
    return d


    activity_df = pandas.read_csv('D:/Ipython/PersonalDataProject/ITRCProject/oneP/activity.csv', index_col=0)
    activity_df['timestamp'] = activity_df['timestamp'].apply(convert_stamp_to_date)
    activity_df = activity_df.drop_duplicates('timestamp')
    activity_df = activity_df['2014-06-28 00:00:00'<activity_df['timestamp']<'2014-06-29 00:00:00']
    activity_df.columns = ['timestamp', 'activity']
```

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        17 activity_df['timestamp'] = activity_df['timestamp'].apply(convert_stamp_to_date)
>        18 activity_df = activity_df.drop_duplicates('timestamp')
>   ---> 19 activity_df = activity_df['2014-06-28 00:00:00'
>
> C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in
>   **nonzero**(self)
>       712         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
>       713                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
>   --> 714                          .format(self.**class**.**name**))
>       715 
>       716     **bool** = **nonzero**
>
> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Sorry your question lacks input data and desired output, also have you looked at [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html#pandas.date_range)?

Comment: How can I filter use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dtm
date1 = dtm.datetime(2014,6,28,0,0,0)
date2 = dtm.datetime(2014,6,29,0,0,0)
#condition = np.logical_and(activity_df>date1,activity_df<date2)
#correction
np.logical_and(activity_df['timestamp']>date1,activity_df['timestamp']<date2)
activity_df = activity_df[condition]
```

Comment: I already try, but it did not work, It just make timestamp NaN value

Comment: I forgot ['timestamp'] in my answer, do you try without this error ? Can you print activity_df['timestamp'].dtypes ?